# Executing SQL JOIN Takes To Long

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables: **patient, obg and doctor**.

Please help me to understand why it's taking so much time (more than 1 minute). When I do not use searchtxt I am getting less time however, if I use searchtxt in some fields I am experiencing delays in retrieving the result.

```
SELECT 
            a.ID AS Pt_ID,
            a.Pt_Name,
            a.Pt_Sex,
            Date_Format(a.Pt_DOB,'%Y/%m/%d') as Pt_DOB,
            a.Pt_Age,
            a.Pt_Opt_HrF,
            a.Pt_HrF_Name,
            a.Pt_Mobile,
            a.Pt_Address,
            b.ID as R_ID,
            Date_Format(b.RP_DATE,'%Y/%m/%d') as RP_DATE,
            b.B_HISTORY,
            b.Ref_Dr_ID,
            Date_Format(b.LMP,'%Y/%m/%d') as LMP,
            b.H_O_G,
            b.P_U_S,
            b.RP_TY,
            b.Ref_Dr_ID,
            c.Dr_Name
 FROM  
    patient a,
    obg b,
    doctor c 
where 

    a.DEL_FLG='N' and b.DEL_FLG='N' and 
    (b.RP_DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['frm_dt']."', '%Y/%m/%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['to_dt']."', '%Y/%m/%d')) and 
   a.ID  LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%'
OR b.ID  LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%'      
OR a.Pt_Name  LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%' 
OR a.Pt_DOB = STR_TO_DATE(".$_POST['searchtxt'].",'%Y/%m/%d')
OR a.Pt_Address LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%'
OR a.Pt_HrF_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%'
OR a.Pt_Mobile LIKE '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%' 
a.ID = b.Pt_ID and 
    b.Ref_Dr_ID = c.ID 
order by b.CRTD_DT Desc
```

Comment: `AND`/`OR` warning...

Comment: Hi jarlh will you please explain me in detail where AND / OR warning but i am getting result for this sql query, its taking more than 1min that is the problem

Comment: maybe you can use whatever version of `for xml path` for mysql and do a like in a single where instead of `OR`ing all those columns.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You may need use [FULL TEXT SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @BharathKumarJ, I suspect you don't get the result you want. `AND` is (logically) evaluated before `OR`. So I guess you shuold do something like `WHERE ... AND (a.ID  LIKE... OR ... OR ...) AND a.ID = b.Pt_ID ...`.

Comment: Your query is not sargable. It is a poor practice to search with a wildcard as the first character. You cannot do that and expect good performance because it can;t use the indexes. You either should require the correct value or at least the first characters or you should use a full text search.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest something like this which will allow you to use like only once without OR's by using concat function - change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  
    patient a,
    obg b,
    doctor c 
where 
    a.DEL_FLG='N' and b.DEL_FLG='N'
    AND (b.RP_DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['frm_dt']."', '%Y/%m/%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['to_dt']."', '%Y/%m/%d')) 
    AND (concat(b.id,'-',a.id,'-',a.Pt_Name,'-',a.Pt_Address,'-',
           a.Pt_HrF_Name,'-',a.Pt_Mobile) LIKE  '%".$_POST['searchtxt']."%'
    OR a.Pt_DOB = STR_TO_DATE(".$_POST['searchtxt'].",'%Y/%m/%d')) 
    AND a.ID = b.Pt_ID  
    AND b.Ref_Dr_ID = c.ID 
order by b.CRTD_DT Desc
```

Also, I think you had a few minor issues with the AND OR AND.. you should use parenthes in this places to make sure that it follow your logic, like in my answer

Comment: This will be easy to read, but doesnt solve the slow problem because this wont use index

Comment: well.. better not using indexes once than at 10 cols

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm sure it will speed up this query eliminating 7 OR's, so its possible it does solve his problem